# Matlab. Place legend outside the plot

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have the following code

```
T = [0:1:30]
a = [5:1:35]; a2 = [0:1:30];
b = [-4:1:26]; b2 = [12:1:42];
c = [16:1:46]; c2 = [15:1:45];
d = [2:1:32]; d2 = [-5:1:25];
figure(1)
title('Time histories of output variables (measured vs estimated)')
subplot(411),plot(T,a, T,a2,'r'); grid; ylabel('p (°/s)'); 
subplot(412),plot(T,b, T,b2,'r'); grid; ylabel('r (°/s)');
subplot(413),plot(T,c, T,c2,'r'); grid; ylabel('phi (º)');
subplot(414),plot(T,d, T,d2,'r'); grid; ylabel('ay (m/s2)');
legend('measured','estimated','Location','bestoutside')
xlabel('Time [s]');
```

Which generates the following plot
[image]

I would like to have the legend outside the plot and that all of them remains with the normal size. (So the legend should be in one of those red circles. Any solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add another [subplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) to act as an empty region to hold only the [legend](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html), with the axes visibility turned off and [`nan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) values for the `'YData'` of the plotted lines, so they don't render:

```
figure(1);
hSub = subplot(511); plot(1, nan, 1, nan, 'r'); set(hSub, 'Visible', 'off');
subplot(512); plot(T, a, T, a2, 'r'); grid; ylabel('p (°/s)');
subplot(513); plot(T, b, T, b2, 'r'); grid; ylabel('r (°/s)');
subplot(514); plot(T, c, T, c2, 'r'); grid; ylabel('phi (º)');
subplot(515); plot(T, d, T, d2, 'r'); grid; ylabel('ay (m/s2)');
xlabel('Time [s]');
legend(hSub, 'measured', 'estimated', 'Location', 'east');
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: I ran the code exctly as you proposed and the empty subplot is there, but the legend is not being displayed. I receive the error "Warning: Plot empty. 
> In legend at 286"

Comment: @FernandoBastosGarcía: What version of MATLAB are you running?

Comment: 2013B. Anyway I found a solution, plot(1,1,1,1, 'r') instead of nans

Comment: @FernandoBastosGarcía: I tested it in R2013a, and it seems that it doesn't like when both the `'XData'` and `'YData'` are set to `nan`. Just setting the `'YData'` to `nan` (and the `'XData'` to anything) fixes it so it works for newer and older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting handle positions using `get` method and manually change positions by doing some arithmetic. For example,

```
T = [0:1:30];
a = [5:1:35]; a2 = [0:1:30];
b = [-4:1:26]; b2 = [12:1:42];
c = [16:1:46]; c2 = [15:1:45];
d = [2:1:32]; d2 = [-5:1:25];
figure(1)

title('Time histories of output variables (measured vs estimated)')

f1 = subplot(411);plot(T,a, T,a2,'r'); grid; ylabel('p (°/s)'); 
pos_f1 = get(f1,'Position');
hl = legend('measured','estimated','Location','bestoutside');
pos_hl = get(hl, 'Position');

subplot(412),plot(T,b, T,b2,'r'); grid; ylabel('r (°/s)');
subplot(413),plot(T,c, T,c2,'r'); grid; ylabel('phi (º)');
subplot(414),plot(T,d, T,d2,'r'); grid; ylabel('ay (m/s2)');

set(hl,'Position',[pos_f1(1)+pos_f1(3)-pos_hl(3)...
pos_hl(2)+pos_hl(4)+0.015...
pos_hl(3)...
0.5*pos_hl(4)]);
```

This should give you:[image: subplot with changed position]

You may need to play around with the parameters in last line, but you get the idea.

Comment: This method is promising, but can be a bit sketchy. If you move it outside of the figure the legend won't show up when you save the figure to a ppt.